# Rounding off of values in matlab

Tags: matlab, rounding, number-formatting

I have some values which are close to zero, and when i run my code, MATLAB rounds off these values to zero.

e.g

```
initial_values = 0.01 0.0002 0.03 0.0004....
```

after running code these values (0.0002 and 0.0004) become zero

```
initial_values = 0.01 0 0.03 0
```

I there some way to prevent this from happening because I need the actual values.

Comment: So what do you do with the values in between? Post code snippet please.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, actually i am using these values in one function which are not rounded off by matlab. But in another function where i reuse these values and multiply them by say q=1, i.e., initial_values_modified = q * (initial_values), matlab roundoff these values to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare at the beginning of your code that you want to use the format long g:

```
format long g
```

In this way the numbers will be displayed in the more readable way between fixed or floating point.

With `format long` you will have:

```
initial_values =   0.010000000000000   0.000200000000000   
                   0.030000000000000   0.000400000000000
```

With `format long g`:

```
initial_values =   0.01  0.0002 0.03 0.0004
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's just a displaying issue. Try `format long` in the command window